# Excel IF function: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am doing some forex trading and I need to use excel, but I have an issue with my code. So I have different currency rates for different amounts of AUD/USD.

| sum | BID (Buy) | BID (Sell) | ASK (Buy) | ASK (Sell) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| < 20,000 AUD | 0.637 | - | - | 0.637 |
| 20,000 - 100,000 AUD | 0.635 | - | - | 0.639 |
| > 100,000 AUD | 0.636 | - | 0.638 | 0.638 |

- When `sum < 20000 AUD`, the exchange rate AUD/USD `= 0.637` for both `BID(buy)` & `ASK(sell)`.
- When `20,000 < sum(buying) < 1,00,000` the price `BID = 0.635` & `sums > 100000` is 0.636.
- When `20,000 < sum(selling) < 1,00,000` the price `ASK = 0.639` & `sums > 100000` is 0.638.

However, I would like to automate the whole process by using two IF functions in two different cells

- one for the BID rate for different sums.
- one for the ASK rate for different sums.

I tried this for calculating the `BID` price but it doesn't work - it only shows the standard rate `0.637`

```
=IF(B5<20000,E4, IF(B5>100000,C5,C4))
```

Please explain what am I doing wrong.

My table looks like that:

[image]

Comment: Why is your column B empty?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that formula.

Comment: There's nothing in cell B5. So your formula will always give the value in E4. I.e. blank < 20000 therefore your formula evaluates to E4

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting to see value of `E4` but you get value of `C5`

What you think wrong is accually not wrong, it's just execution order.

Your formula is `=IF(B5<20000;E4; IF(B5>100000;C5;C4))` and lets say values are;

- `B5` is `200000`
- `E4` is `100`
- `C4` is `200`
- `C5` is `300`

Calculation starts from inner parentheses so calculation steps as below;

1. `=IF(B5<20000;E4; IF(B5>100000;C5;C4))`
2. `=IF(B5<20000;E4; IF(200000>100000;300;200))`
3. `=IF(B5<20000;E4; 300)`
4. `300`

I don't see anything wrong actually it's completely logic.